# file system with C++

Tags: c++, filesystems

i have to do this using C++
I have to make a file system. At the initialization of file system, a 10 MB file should be initialized. file should be divided into 3  parts.
First portion (1MB) of file “File_system” should be reserved for the file names and the  starting address of the data in the file. It should be subdivided into sub blocks, each of capacity  500B. In other words, each sub block in the first block (1 MB) of the file should have a capacity  to store file name and starting address which should not exceed 500B. 
Second portion (1MB) of your file “File_system” for listing the available  empty blocks in the third portion.
Third portion (8MB) of your file “File_system” for the data to be written in  the files listed in first portion.
I know file handling, link list, trees, classes.
i haven't got any clue how to give a start.How to allocate space in a text file.

Comment: how would you do it if you had all in memory?

Comment: exactly i don't know how to create a text file of 10 MB and hw to divide it. Its in memory :/

Comment: Well, you certainly want to use a binary file, not a text file.  To create the file, write 10mb of data to it, perhaps all zeroes.  The division isn't part of the file, but your logic for manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically do this by defining some structures to represent the data for each part. For example, your first part (the 500 byte) structures would be something like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or equivalent
struct directory_entry { 
    long starting_address;
    char file_name[500-sizeof(long);
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

For the file, you're going to want an array of those occupying 1 megabyte.

The second portion is probably easiest to set up as a bitmap. Decide on a size of block to use for the storage itself. For simplicity, let's say 1 kilobyte. So, you'll treat the 8 MB of the third part as an array of 1 KB blocks. The second part will have one bit devoted to each 1 KB block. It'll be 0 if that block is free, and 1 if that block is in use.

You might initialize it by setting everything to 0-bytes. Then to create a file, you'll scan through the directory entry portion until you find an entry with its starting_address still set to 0. You'll then scan through the bitmap in the second portion to find some space you can use. You'll set the bit for that space to 1, and set the starting_address in the directory entry to the address corresponding to the block you found that's not in use.

To support multiple blocks in a file, you could (for one example) devote the last 4 bytes of each block to the address of the next block that makes up that file (and some otherwise impossible value signifying the end of the file). That's not the most efficient way to do things for most purposes, but it's probably sufficient for the task at hand.

Of course, there are lots of alternatives to each of these. What I've outlined is a really simple, but (to be honest) quite inefficient type of file system vaguely similar to what you might have seen on a *really* low-end computer 30+ years ago--but just for an obvious example, even the MS-DOS FAT file system was more sophisticated.